# Why am I getting a No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, cors

[Chrome authorization Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijDpQ.jpg)

I believe I have cors configured correctly in my backend. The API is hosted on Heroku if that helps. Here is the server.js file:

```js
const express = require("express");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const productsRouter = require("./products/products-router");
const ordersRouter = require("./orders/orders-router");
const emailsRouter = require("./emails/emails-router");

const corsOptions = {
  origin: "*",
  credentials: true,
  optionSuccessStatus: 200,
};
const server = express();
server.use(express.json());
server.use(helmet());
server.use(cors(corsOptions));

server.use("/api/products", productsRouter);
server.use("/api/orders", ordersRouter);
server.use("/api/emails", emailsRouter);

server.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(err.status || 500).json({
    message: err.message,
  });I
});

module.exports = server;
```

I get a cors error when my front-end tries to make HTTP requests to the backend. It reads as follows:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://nanasoapsbackend.herokuapp.com/api/products/categories' from
> origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Yes, my back and and front end are on different domains. This just happened all of a sudden, it was working fine with no cors errors for the past few months, and suddenly it stopped working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error seems self descriptive here. You can also verify the returned headers in the chrome network tab.

Comment: Did you add authorization? Did you update your browser?

Comment: I added an image of my authorization headers. not sure what to make of it. I did update my browser. What do you mean by add authorization?

Comment: Is it really a CORS issue? Did you checked the backend for errors? Recently I faced with this kind of scenario. It seems currently the console is misleading with CORS errors, but actually it was a different one. You can your api, if there’s any error.

Comment: I don't think so.. I have extensive tests written for the back end, and they all pass. But I'll try to go over it manually.

Comment: I just got this error today, where you able to get it fix @MaratKotik?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is: You can't have origin * (allow everything) with allow credentials. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials

You have to set up a white list (list of domains that are allowed)

```
const whitelist = ['http://www.example.com', 'http://www.otherexample.com']
const corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.includes(origin)) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed'))
    }
  }
}
```

Then on your client side (frontend) make sure you use withCredientals flag on your http agent (axios, superagent, fetc, etc)